# Is it possible to save Jupyter notebook checkpoints in a different dir?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

For example, I have a notebook file in `/src/notebook/nb1.ipynb` and the Jupyter notebook will create a hidden dir `/src/notebook/.ipython_checkpoints`. Is there a settings/config to tell the Jupyter to save the checkpoint in a different directory, for example `/tmp/.ipython_checkpoints`.